# Logging level of Google Cloud Profiler Java agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-profiler

How to change the log level of Java profiler? I am running the profiler outside GCP.

Although, Profiler is working fine. It is repeatedly logging following errors:

```
E0803 12:37:37.677731 22 cloud_env.cc:61] Request to the GCE metadata server failed, status code: 404
E0803 12:37:37.677788 22 cloud_env.cc:148] Failed to read the zone name
```

How can I disable these logs?

Answer (score 0):

For Stackdriver Logging you can use log [exclusion filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#exclusion-filters) to create customised filters for logs you want to exclude.

In the Logs Viewer panel, you can enter a filter expression that matches the log entry you want to exclude. [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#the_user_interfaces) explains about various interfaces to create filters.

You may also want to export the log entries before excluding them, if you do not want to permanently lose the excluded logs.

With respect to this issue in general (i.e. for third party logging), I went ahead and created a feature request on your behalf. Please star it so that you could receive updates about this feature request and do not hesitate to add additional comments to provide details of the desired implementation. You can track the feature request by following [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112456173).

Comment: I am running profiler outside GCP. I am not using Stackdriver Logging.

Comment: If you are not seeing these errors in Stackdriver Logging, where do you see them? In general, these just mean that the Profiler cannot connect to the instance metadata server, which makes perfect sense if you are using the Profiler outside of GCP on a machine that is not a part of the GCP infrastructure.

Comment: I am able to see them in third party logging providers which aggregates application stdout. Is there a way I can configure the logging level of profiler to disable these logs. It prints these logs twice every minute. It would be fine if these are printed only once on startup and not every minute

Comment: @Sunil Kumar Please have a look at my updated answer.